# How can I contstruct this T-SQL query involving missing date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'll try to keep the specific details of my problem out of this question and focus only on the pertinent issues.

Lets say I have an `Assets` table with a primary key of `AssetID`. 
I have another table called `ProcessedDates` with primary key `PID` and with additional columns `AssetID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`.
I want to run a process for a list of assets between a start date and end date. 
Before I can run this process, I need to know which assets and which date ranges have already been processed.

For example, there are 2 entries in ProcessedDates:

```
AssetID  StartDate  EndDate
--------------------------
Asset1   Day4       day7
Asset1   Day10      Day12
```

I want to process Asset1 between day2 and day11. I don't need to waste time by processing on days that have already been done so in this example, I will only process asset1 from day2 to day3 and from day8 to day 9.

So what I need is a query that returns the gaps in the date ranges. In this case, the result set will be 2 lines:

```
AssetID  StartDate  EndDate
--------------------------
Asset1   day2       day3
Asset1   day8       day9
```

In my actual requirement I have many assetIDs. The `ProcessedDates` table may have multiple entries for each asset or none at all and each asset does not necessarily have the same processed dates as any other asset.

```
declare @StartDate date, @EndDate date (assume these are given)

--get distinct assets
select distinct AssetIDs from (some query) into #Assets
--get the already processed date ranges
select p.AssetID, p.StartDate, p.EndDate
from ProcessedDates p inner join #Assets a on p.AssetID = a.AssetID
where p.StartDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
or p.EndDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

From here I have no clue how to proceed. How do I get it to return `AssetID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate` for all the gaps in between?

Comment: Let's say you have sample data and desired results.  Then it would be much easier to communicate what your problem is.

Comment: Some things are better done in code that in tsql... this is probably one of those things... it is feasible to do it in tsql but it will get ugly...

Comment: Gordon, xanatos has kindly reformatted my question to highlight the included sample data and desired results. Thanks xanatos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
declare @StartDate date = '2015-01-01', @EndDate date = '2015-05-05'

declare @Assets table (AssetID varchar(50), StartDate date, EndDate date)
declare @AssetTypes table (AssetID varchar(50))

insert into @AssetTypes values
('Asset1'), 
('Asset2')

insert into @Assets values
('Asset1', '2014-12-10', '2014-12-31'), -- Ignored
('Asset1', '2015-02-02', '2015-03-02'),
('Asset1', '2015-03-05', '2015-05-01'),
('Asset1', '2015-06-01', '2015-06-06') -- Ignored

;WITH Base AS (
    SELECT AT.AssetID
        , CASE WHEN A.AssetID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END EmptyAsset
        , A.StartDate
        , A.EndDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AT.AssetID ORDER BY StartDate) RN
        FROM @AssetTypes AT
        LEFT JOIN @Assets A ON A.AssetID = AT.AssetID
        WHERE A.AssetID IS NULL -- case of totally missing asset
            OR (StartDate <= @EndDate AND EndDate >= @StartDate)
)

-- first missing range, before the first row
SELECT AssetID, @StartDate StartDate, DATEADD(dd, -1, StartDate) EndDate
    FROM Base 
    WHERE RN = 1 AND StartDate > @StartDate

UNION ALL

-- each row joined with the next one
SELECT B1.AssetID, DATEADD(dd, 1, B1.EndDate), ISNULL(DATEADD(dd, -1, B2.StartDate), @EndDate)
    FROM Base B1
    LEFT JOIN Base B2 ON B2.AssetID = B1.AssetID AND B2.RN = B1.RN + 1
    WHERE B1.EmptyAsset = 0
        AND (B2.AssetID IS NULL -- Last row case
            OR DATEADD(dd, 1, B1.EndDate) < B2.StartDate) -- Other rows case
        AND B1.EndDate < @EndDate -- If the range ends after @EndDate, nothing to do

UNION ALL

-- case of totally missing asset
SELECT AssetID, @StartDate, @EndDate
    FROM Base 
    WHERE EmptyAsset = 1
```

The main idea is that each row is joined with the next one. A new range is generated (if necessary) between the EndDate + 1 and the StartDate - 1. There is a special handling for the last row (`B2.AssetID IS NULL` and `ISNULL(... @EndDate)`). The first `SELECT` generated a row before the first range, and the last select is for the special case of no ranges present for an asset.

As I've written in the comments, it gets ugly quite quickly.

Comment: I see what you mean by ugly but this is ugly in an elegant sort of way! I'm not yet sure if I will use this or go with your earlier suggestion of doing it in the code but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an simple version to get the result you want. I use integer as date, and assume the min date is 0 and the max date is 999.

```
--DDL
create table Assets  (AssetID integer, StartDate integer, EndDate integer);
insert into Assets values
(1,4,7),
(1,10,12),
(1,15,17),
(2,5,7),
(2,9,10);

with temp as(
select a1.AssetId,
       a1.enddate+1 as StartDate, 
       coalesce(min(a2.startdate) - 1,999) as EndDate
from Assets a1
left join Assets a2
on a1.assetid = a2.assetid
and a1.enddate < a2.startdate
group by a1.assetid,a1.enddate  
union all
select a.assetid,0,min(startdate) -1
from Assets a
group by a.assetid
)
select AssetId,
       case when StartDate<2 then 2 else StartDate end as StartDate,
       case when EndDate>11 then 11 else EndDate   end as EndDate
from temp
where StartDate<=11 and EndDate>=2
order by AssetId,StartDate
```

The temp table can get the missing ranges. Then filter the match ranges between Day2 and Day11, will get the result that you want.

```
AssetId StartDate   EndDate
1   2   3
1   8   9
2   2   4
2   8   8
2   11  11
```

Here's the [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96775/4)